# Populate HTML Table with fetched SQL Data - Implement Table Class

Tags: html, mysql, css

I have a query which returns correct results form the database, I want to populate a HTML table with the results. However, I only get the data "raw" displayed, the table is not displayed like it should be according to the CSS class.

My question: Are my table class tags placed at the correct point? I think here is the error somewhere.

```
  <table class="table-class">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Car</th><th>Year</th><th>HP</th><th>Seats</th></tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    while($row = $resultsql->fetch_assoc()){
?>

<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row['Car']; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row['Year']; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row['HP']; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row['Seats']; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
.table-class  {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .table-class {
    width: auto;
  }
}
.table-class  tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-class  tr td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .table-class  tr td {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.table-class  tr td:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
.table-class  th {
  display: none;
}
.table-class  td {
  display: block;
}
.table-class  td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.table-class  td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.table-class  td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 9em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .table-class  td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.table-class  th:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
.table-class  th, .table-class  td {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .table-class  th, .table-class  td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .table-class  th:first-child, .table-class  td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .table-class  th:last-child, .table-class  td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the CSS code in your question? Anything containing `.table-class` should be included.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but aren't you missing the `<tbody>…</tbody>` tags? The `<table class="table-class">` is right, btw.

Comment: Uhh, I think i got it: The while-loop lacks the closing `}`.

Comment: @PerlDog that didn't do the trick, but thanks, missed that. Where to the tbody tags go?

Comment: The missing `}` is ok? Wow, PHP is a cool language then, as it knows where the `while` ends. And for tbody: correct would be `<table><thead>…</thead><tbody><tr>…</tr><tr>…</tr></tbody></table>`

Comment: @PerlDog If I add the <tbody> tags inside the while, it gives me an error that the else (further down) corresponding to that whole If loop is unexpected.

Comment: I meant `<tbody><?php.....?></tbody>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102139/discussion-between-perl-dog-and-felix-f).

Comment: i don't see an if statement in your code! there is nothing called while-else statement in php, i think you should remove the else block. also can we see the html result?

Comment: @HussainAlmomen The If statement is further above, it works, I get the correct results. The data gets displayed "table like", like in rows in columns, but not CSS-formatted.

Comment: can you show us the result in browser? screenshot or the actual page link?

Comment: @HussainAlmomen Sure, here: http://imgur.com/EVs0ZiE

Comment: @FelixF. That completely changes things. I thought you see only garbage or the php code or something in the browser. Have you included your CSS into your page? no typos? Instead of `<table class=...>` try out `<table style="color:blue;">` and see if it's blue then.

Comment: @FelixF. What are you looking to change on the table with the CSS?

Comment: @PerlDog Wow, okay, so its blue now. That means something is wrong with my css. Thanks, I post the solution when I found it.

Comment: @SaucedApples I just want to apply a class to the table.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what class is not working for you?

Comment: @SaucedApples The class "table-class", the CSS is also posted above in the question.

Comment: @FelixF. I pasted your css into [a CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input). It has syntax errors.

Comment: table-class in the entire css file, WHAT ACTUALLY are you expecting to happen?  Please post the entire page code

Comment: @PerlDog Yes, had same idea, fixed the errors, still nothing.

Comment: @SaucedApples Look, I got the table template from here, just wanted to populate it, thats it: http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg

Comment: Do you have the slightest clue?  You have populated it.  Do you not remember linking to an image showing populated data from a database?

Comment: @SaucedApples Sir, I don't know what you are trying to tell me, I know that I've populated it, the problem is the CSS-Class applied to it isn't working. There is no reason to be so harsh.

Comment: @SaucedApples No comment on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues about your code:

(1) Each `<td>` should have their respective `<th>` values as their `data-th` attribute and this is missing.

```
<?php
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td data-th="Car">' . $row['Car'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td data-th="Year">' . $row['Year'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td data-th="HP">' . $row['HP'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td data-th="Seats">' . $row['Seats'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
?>
```

(2) The border properties should be added to the `<td>` tags and not the `<tr>` tags. Table rows do not support this property. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbdyv3u4/).

Well, I have made a few modifications to the CSS code (basically put all the media queries together), but it demonstrates how you can add borders to your table and use `<th>` data in a responsive way.

Comment: This works in terms of that I see the CSS working, thank you very much. However, it doesn't look like the codepen example. Am I misunderstanding something, do I miss some code to make it look like it?

Comment: I had not even noticed the pen (until now). It appeared to me that you needed support on using the data attribute and making the table border work and that's what I tried to help about. I think you can do the rest easily, adding some background, border radius, colors, fonts, etc. Piece of cake... Right? Let me know if you get stuck and I'll try to get you through.